# Loading simple XML file not working, educational game

Tags: xml, unity-game-engine, xml-parsing

Hi guys I though you might be able to help me. Making simple educational quiz-type game, and I got stuck on the last step > I cant load the data from XML file. 
Here is an example of xml file.

```
<QuestionData>
<Question>
<questionText>4+4?</questionText>
<answerA>1</answerA>
<answerB>2</answerB>
<answerC>8</answerC>
 <answerD>4</answerD>
<correctAnswer>8</correctAnswer>
 </Question>
 <Question> 
   .......(another question+answers)
 </Question>
  </QuestionData>
```

This should load the XML data

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System;

public struct Question {
public string questionText;
public string answerA;
public string answerB;
public string answerC;
public string answerD;
public string correctAnswerID; 
}

[XmlRoot]

public class QuestionData {
[XmlArray("questions")]
[XmlArrayItem("Question")]
public List<Question> questions = new List<Question>();

public static QuestionData LoadFromText(string text) {
    try {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QuestionData));            
        return serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(text)) as QuestionData;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(e);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

**Now, this is the script where I will attach the data to particular gameobjects. However, the loading of xml data doesnt seem to work at all.**

```
public class QuestionLoading : MonoBehaviour {
[SerializeField]
public TextAsset questionDataXMLFile;
public QuestionData questionData;
public Question currentQuestion;
void Start() {


    questionData = QuestionData.LoadFromText(questionDataXMLFile.text);
    Debug.Log (questionData.questions.Count);
    Debug.Log (currentQuestion.questionText);
 }
```

**When I am debugging questionData.questions.Count and currentQuestion I am always getting 0 value. Any idea why?**

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the xml objects to classes with xml attribute declarations.  Also I do not see you assigning `currentQuestion` to anything.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Question")]
public class Question
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "questionText")]
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "answerA")]
    public string AnswerA { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "answerB")]
    public string AnswerB { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "answerC")]
    public string AnswerC { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "answerD")]
    public string AnswerD { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "correctAnswer")]
    public string CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "QuestionData")]
public class QuestionData
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Question")]
    public List<Question> Question { get; set; }

    static public QuestionData LoadFromText(string text)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QuestionData));
            return serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(text)) as QuestionData;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU, that solved my problem :) Everything works now...really thanks a lot!